# Move the Object in y-axis when the timer increases

Tags: c#, unity, timer, axis

I have a model(.Fbx object),I have placed a timer.When the timer starts increasing the model/object should move down(along y axis).

Comment: This question does not appear to show any research effort; moving an object over time is a very basic task that would be covered in any unity tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Have a look at lerp. You'll be able to move to a position over time like this:

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( start, end, currentTime / totalTime );
```

Where start is the initial position of the object you are moving and end is the place you want to be once currentTime = totalTime. In your case, the end vector would be directly below the object that is being moved.

If you want constant movement while the timer is running, then make sure you know when the timer is running and just do something like this:

```
if( timerIsRunning )
{
    transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```